# Not able to read # from query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string, request.querystring

In my application user can change the query string value, for one of the key we are supporting all the special characters.

when i read the query string using below code

```
Request.QueryString["key"]
```

all the characters after `#` is getting trimmed.

we cannot support all the special characters ? Is there any alternatives ?

Thanks

Comment: The hash part is only used and available on the client side. You cannot read it from ASP.NET / C#

Comment: It's in the query string as `%23` rather than as `#`, yes?

Comment: As per the specification, [fragments](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3) are not sent to the server.

Answer (score 4):

The hash part of the url or [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) is only available client side and as such will not be sent to the server.  If you wish to send across the hash character you need to encode it which is %23.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your hash sign with %23

This is just encoding the hash sign.